# Debian-Thunderbird: set 2-factor authentication for a GMX account

Tags: linux, thunderbird

I have just added this functionality to an e-mail account and can't get Thunderbird to authenticate, the error message is "The server does not support the selected authentication method" so I am not sure if is something related to GMX or to Thunderbird. I wrote to GMX's customer support to ask this but didn't get any response yet.

The settings are: IMAP server with SSL/TLS and "OAuth2" (imap.gmx.com) and SMTP server (mail.gmx.com) with with SSL/TLS and "OAuth2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Who told you GMX supports OAuth2? ;-) Why did you enable it nilly-willy? ;-) Google/GMail supports it, correct, it doesn't mean all other email providers do.

Comment: @Thanks. I googled it and found few comments but nothing clear enough. Do you know for sure GMX doesn't provide this functionality? It's nice that is available but becomes a big issue for the end user if you cannot use an e-mail app... but maybe is just how it is.

Comment: google: `oauth2 site:gmx.com` returns nothing, isn't that enough?